# How do I reverse this simply modulus 128 encryption?

Tags: java, math, encryption

I'm running a simple program where I convert a String into an array of chars, and then convert the chars into integers, where I then add or subtract numbers to them, in order to encrypt the string. My only problem is, I'm stuck when it comes to decrypting what I just encrypted.

using this:

```
num % 128 + 65
```

The String "hello world" is changed to "uryy|-E|Àyq"

I can't seem to be able to figure out how to change it back.

Comment: Decryption is reversing what you've applied to encrypt.  Essentially, an inverse function.  The trick is knowing the properties of modulus, which is more a math question than a programming question.

Comment: When u use a plain mod operator, the answer cannot be reversed to get the question back. I guess the exact decryption is not possible in this case.

Comment: How is `h%128 + 65` = `u`?

Comment: Standard ASCII only has 128 characters so taking the modulo 128 of this is useless. You simply add 65. The reverse function of adding 65 is subtracting 65 :) But that somehow is not what your result string looks like.

Comment: What type of characters you have? If you use the full ASCII table (not to mention mufti-byte Unicode codes) you will not be able to "undo" your so called encryption.

Answer (score 3):

In order to have a valid encryption function in the first place, the function needs to be injective. Then it can be reversed and only then.

Modulo is not injective. 1 and 129 % 128 are both 1. So, there's no reverse function for your encryption method.

Answer (score 2):

```
f(x) = x % 128 + 65
```

this function is irreversible, it's not a linear encryption function, it's a hash function

```
g(x):
   g(X0) = X0 ^ KEY
   g(Xi) = Xi ^ Xi-1
```

g(x) is an encryption function using a KEY, to decrypt we use g(x) itself again, since XOR is a symmetric operation

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You've lost information: the high bit of each byte. There is no inverse of this function. So it's not an encryption function at all.

And that function does not deliver that output from that input.